# Getting credit for trying?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

Is there an idiom, saying, or an epigram that expresses the meaning of getting the credit for trying even without the success of outcome?

Comment: "Well, ya gotta give him credit for tryin'."

Answer (score 3):

Frequently you hear this in the context you refer to: 
"He gets an 'A' for effort"

Comment: Except sometimes it's "E for effort".